# AppleScript - Control Position of Dialog Windows in Logic Pro

Tags: applescript, logic

Having a problem.

I am able to control the position of the standard windows in Logic Pro fine with basic Applescript but when I try 1 of the Plugin windows, it doesn't work.

Heres my script:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Logic Pro X"
        activate
        set position of the window "Audio 1" to {50, 500}
        get properties of the window "Audio 1"
    end tell
end tell
```

The "get properties" returns:

Result:
`{minimum value:missing value, orientation:missing value, position:{609, 246}, class:window, role description:"dialog", accessibility description:missing value, focused:true, title:"Audio 1", size:{737, 515}, value:missing value, help:missing value, enabled:missing value, maximum value:missing value, role:"AXWindow", entire contents:{}, subrole:"AXDialog", selected:missing value, name:"Audio 1", description:"dialog"}`

get confirms that its a window and has a position property, so apparently its gettable but not settable.
Anyone know what I am missing? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with TextEdit and was astonished that it *really* wouldn't start...
Then I became suspicious about the "**process**" - when the app doesn't run (at least in background) there's actually no "**process**" to activate, is there?
And yes, it worked for me with:

```
[...] tell application "TextEdit" [...]
```

(If that still fails, you might add a **delay 1** after the **activate** - registering  an app takes time.)